# Select a value from list of options in a SELECT element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

Is there a JavaScript member function to select by value (set as selected) one of the OPTIONs in a SELECT tag? Is it cross-browser?

```
<select id="mySelect">
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">One</option>
</select>
```

If not, what's a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup:

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').value = "2";
```

Where `"2"` is the `value` of the option you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to set you can use something like

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").options[OPTION_ID].selected = true;
```

Where OPTION_ID is a valid option index.

Comment: Cool. I meant to say select by value. Edited question.

Comment: No worries; if you ever need to set by option index you're also set.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
sel.selectedIndex =1;
```

the selectedIndex begins from zero.